# Change the value of a Clojure var without touching the metadata

Tags: clojure, metadata

I've been working on the assumption that a var's metadata is "stable," that is, I can change the var's value without changing the var's metadata. Now I see there's something wrong with my understanding. Code:

```
(def ^{:Metadata "metaA"} A 1)  ;; Define A with value 1 and metadata.
=> #'thic.core/A
(def ^{:Metadata "metaB"} B 2)  ;; Define B with value 2 and metadata.
=> #'thic.core/B
A                               ;; A's value is 1.
=> 1
B                               ;; B's value is 2.
=> 2
(meta (var A))
=>
{:Metadata "metaA",             ;; A has the defined metadata.
 :line 1,
 :column 1,
 :file "C:\\Users\\Joe User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\form-init2487748963910096550.clj",
 :name A,
 :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x147c445 "thic.core"]}
(meta (var B))
=>
{:Metadata "metaB",             ;; So does B.
 :line 1,
 :column 1,
 :file "C:\\Users\\Joe User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\form-init2487748963910096550.clj",
 :name B,
 :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x147c445 "thic.core"]}
(def B A)                       ;; Give B A's value,
=> #'thic.core/B
A
=> 1
B                               ;; which it now has,
=> 1
(meta (var B))                  ;; and B's previously-defined metadata is gone.
=>
{:line 1,
 :column 1,
 :file "C:\\Users\\Joe User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\form-init2487748963910096550.clj",
 :name B,
 :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x147c445 "thic.core"]}
(meta (var A))                  ;; A's remains unchanged.
=>
{:Metadata "metaA",
 :line 1,
 :column 1,
 :file "C:\\Users\\Joe User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\form-init2487748963910096550.clj",
 :name A,
 :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x147c445 "thic.core"]}
```

Is there a way I can assign the value of A to B without wiping out the metadata in B?
Or maybe I just don't understand the difference between "binding" and "assignment"?
*Clojure in Action 2nd Edition* says "When new values are created from those that have metadata, the metadata is copied over to the new data." (p. 57) My example is not **creating** a new value. Is that the problem? I *still* want to modify a var's value without modifying its metadata.
I humbly beseech thee, ClojureGods.

Comment: could you please elaborate on why would you need to redefine the var with `def`. What is the use case?. That really looks unidiomatic in clojure. Though `alter-var-root` would do this, still maybe there is a better way to implement your desired functionality.

Comment: leetwinski: I'm not married to a 'def' to change a var's value, if there is any other way to do so that doesn't alter the metadata. It's just the only way my limited knowledge of Clojure tells me how it's done. Your suggestions are appreciated, as is your interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alter-var-root` can do that.

```
-------------------------
clojure.core/alter-var-root
([v f & args])
  Atomically alters the root binding of var v by applying f to its
  current value plus any args
```

E.g.:

```
; Clojure 1.10.3
(def ^{:Metadata "metaA"} A 1)
; #'user/A
(def ^{:Metadata "metaB"} B 2)
; #'user/B
A
; 1
B
; 2
(meta #'A)
; {:Metadata "metaA", :line 1, :column 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :name A, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x2189e7a7 "user"]}
(meta #'B)
; {:Metadata "metaB", :line 1, :column 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :name B, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x2189e7a7 "user"]}
(alter-var-root #'B (constantly A))
; 1
B
; 1
(meta #'B)
; {:Metadata "metaB", :line 1, :column 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :name B, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x2189e7a7 "user"]}
```

Comment: Thank you, cfrick. With 6 Clojure books and only 2 mentioning this intrinsic, clearly I am not supposed to alter the root value of a var. Clojure is a "whole 'nother" kind of programming language which, eventually, I will get used to and good at.

Comment: @LionelGoulet If you see this in the wild, it's most likely around "dev tooling".  E.g. some `user.clj` for reloading systems or really replacing something for dev or testing. Assuming that the later is something you are after...